# How to get last 2 numbers from X cell and add them before @ in Y cell?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I need a formula to auto get the last two numbers from Birthday row and add them in the Email row before the `@` symbol like this:
`afscghnaba**97**@example.com`
screenshot for explaining what I want to do:

[image: example]

Sheet URL: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XHoxD-hNmpUOMVm_u-cz-4ESrabodsrS0fIfaN-n4js/edit

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the [RIGHT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087) function, like `RIGHT(D2:D,2)`, in your existing formula

```
=INDEX(IF(C2:C="","",LOWER(SUBSTITUTE(C2:C," ",""))&
                     RIGHT(D2:D,2)&"@example.com"),)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @marikamitsos, the formula works well in the Sheet I've shared with you, but when I copy it and want to use it in my private sheet it gives me an error: https://i.imgur.com/AeqzJZ1.png , any solution to make it works on that Sheet too? Thank you

Comment: The given error means that you have some data in cell`I27` (and maybe further down). You need to remember that **the whole range of cells affected by any `INDEX` formula has to be cleared for the formula to work**.

Comment: Yes, you're right! after I cleared the cell I27, the formula works well now :) Thank you so much @marikamitsos